# How do I install the Sun Java Development Kit (JDK 7)?

Tags: installation, java, jdk, tar

How to install JDK 7 on Ubuntu?

The installation should be with the tar archive.

I know the basic installation with the bin, but how to do with only a tar archive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally when using a tar archive, you'd just add the path to the compiler executable in the extracted tar file to your `$PATH` variable, or if you're using an IDE like Eclipse, specify the compiler manually.

Answer (score 1):

If you like the easy way you can use webupd8 java ppa, then there is no of installing it by the tar file:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

http://www.webupd8.org/2013/06/oracle-releases-java-7-update-25-7u25.html

Alter Install you can change the default java-version by

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference between .bin and tar archive is that, .bin is self extracting while tar archive will require you to use a third part application like "tar" command in linux to extract its contents.

To do so in extract a tar archive in ubuntu on command line type:-

```
tar xvf <tar-archive-filename>
```