# How to install Java development kit 8 on 64 bit Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, jdk

I have been using Ubuntu as my first flavour of Linux for about a week. I am facing problem installing the Sun Java Development Kit (JDK 8)

The downloaded files are in .tar.gz extension, i have gone through the readme which is present in the folder and still facing trouble extracting and installing the file, Readme file for reference is in the below link :

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/linux_jdk.html#BJFJJEFG

The .tar.gz file is in my downloads folder, i used terminal to go to the same directory, ls output of the Downloads below, shows the extracted and unextracted folders:

```
jdk1.8.0_77

jdk-8u77-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

I executed the command as mentioned in the readme with the following output :

```
:~/Downloads# % tar zxvf jdk-8u77-linux-x64.tar.gz
bash: fg: %: no such job
```

I have gone through the previously asked question

[How do I install the Sun Java Development Kit (JDK 7)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41606/how-do-i-install-the-sun-java-development-kit-jdk-7)

I thought after install i could figure a way out to update it, however it did not help. I tried changing the default java version, got the below output:

```
update-alternatives --config java
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

Selection Path                                    Priority     Status
--------------------------------------------------
* 0     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java       1072     auto mode 
 1     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java 1071     manual mode
 2    /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java         1072     manual mode
```

Any information to help me resolve this issue would be much appreciated. I am new to the linux environment.

FYI: I have tried to unpack and install the file as both root and non root user. Due to the fact that this is my first post, i am unable to paste more than two links, if anyone requires to be directed to any link with which i was working on, let me know and i will share the same.

Comment: Why do you have the `%` in `% tar zxvf jdk-8u77-linux-x64.tar.gz`?

Comment: @Zacharee1, the exact syntax was in the read me, i also tried the command without % before making this post, it was not able to resolve the issue either.

Comment: why do not you install it more simpler way like so ` sudo apt-get install python-software-properties` 
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java`
`sudo apt-get update` `sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer` after installing change the version if you JDK7 `sudo update-alternatives --config java`

Comment: @Zacharee1, it worked this time, i am quiet sure i tried it few times without %, however i must have been missing something.I tried to paste the truncated output of the terminal below  but there are many characters .

After this i ran apt-get update, however when i checked the java version, it now shows as 
javac -version
javac 1.7.0_80

as oppsoed to previous : 
javac -version
javac 1.7.0_95 .

What is the next step, do i have to execute any install command (if at all)?

Comment: @bhordupur, i have tried doing that, you can go through my initial post, it does not work, i have also cited a previous post with the same solution.

Comment: Strange.This is the easiest and eficient way  since u get the update from its repository.But any way why did u have % before tar.

Comment: @ Zacharee, @bhordupur, i was trying to get this update installed as a root user, and while executing apt-get update the version finally got upgraded. Not sure if the .tar.gz file worked or the other commands to add the ppa as i had not executed any commands before asking the system to update. New output of javac -version : javac -version
  javac 1.8.0_77 .  Now i encounter an error notification on the lines of "system program problem detected", i  deleted the logs but i guess i need to uninstall the java 8 ppa and lock the java7 till a stable version is released. Thankyou for your inputs.